# Combining Data from Two Tables into One Row

Tags: sql

I've read around quite a bit for a solution to my problem but I can't seem to get it to work. It seems like a simple problem but I'm not getting the result set I want.

I'm working on a report that needs to pull from two tables and essentially create one row of data for each employee. The file needs to be uploaded to a healthcare vendor.

Here is an example of the data

Table1: EmployeeCheckDeduction

```
Employee ID  Deduction Amount  Check Date
       1234             50.00   6/30/2015
       1234             50.00   7/15/2015
       4567            100.00   6/30/2015
       4567            100.00   7/15/2015
       9876             75.00   6/30/2015
       9876             75.00   7/15/2015
```

Table2: EmployerContribution

```
Employee ID  Contribution Amount  Check Date
       1234                25.00   6/30/2015 
       1234                30.00   7/15/2015
       4567                50.00   6/30/2015
       4567                60.00   7/15/2015
```

Part of the problem is that not every record in Table1 will have a corresponding match in Table 2. If they are maxed out on contributions, they won't receive one on that pay. What I want is a result set that looks like this:

```
Employee ID  Deduction Amount  Contribution Amount  Check Date
       1234             50.00                25.00   6/30/2015
       1234             50.00                30.00   7/15/2015 
       4567            100.00                50.00   6/30/2015
       4567            100.00                60.00   7/15/2015
       9876             75.00                 0.00   6/30/2015
       9876             75.00                 0.00   7/15/2015
```

No matter how I try and join, it's just duplicating data. I've tried using subqueries or distinct records and no matter what I try, it's not giving me what I want. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Edit. See links below for dataset results.

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01551050904538574848

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=63978789937644749322

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=28700836121558977952

I think part of the problem is that in the Employee Check Deduction table there is a specific deduction code that I'm pulling out. In the employer deduction table that code also exists. However, whenever I try and add the join on those 2 fields in addition to employee ID and check date, it doesn't return results from the employees who have a deduction amount in the employee check deduction table when they don't have a corresponding record in the Employer Contribution Table. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.employee_id, a.deduction_amount, b.contribution_amount, 
a.check_date 
from employeecheckdeduction a join employercontribution b
 on a.employee_id = b.employee_id
 and a.check_date = b.check_date
```

Try this by renaming the columns if necessary. You should join on employed and checkdate.

Comment: That was actually my first idea and it doesn't match up. It returns everything correctly for the employee check deduction but I don't get the correct amount from the employer contribution. I can't figure out why if I'm joining on both the ID and check date, that it doesn't return corresponding values from the second table.

Comment: what database are you using ? and what are the datatypes of those columns?

Comment: also it would help if you could post the results you see now

Comment: The software is ADP Enterprise using SQL 2008. I'll try and post a screenshot of the SQL results. Maybe part of the problem is that inside of these tables, it stores all check deductions. I'm just looking for one specific code and I have that included in my where clause. I think the problem is with the Employer Contribution table.

Comment: See the bottom of the original post. I updated with links so you can see the results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are dealing with TWO different things:

a) You want a FULL list of all employees who have ever had a contribution AND/OR a deduction

b) You then want to display it in one row

While there are many ways to go about this, the first thing would be two separate out those two and handle them.

Also it is not clear if you want to GROUP BY the employee ID or if you want to see a full history. If you are to look at history, the best thing would be using a FULL JOIN such as:

```
select coalesce(d.employee_id,c.employee_id) employee_id
     , d.deduction_amount 
     , c.contribution_amount
     , coalesce(d.deducation_date,c.contribution_date) check_date
from employee_deduction d
    full join employee_contribution c on c.employee_id = d.employee_id

where d.DED_CD = 'H' or c.MEMO_CD = 'H'
```

What a `FULL JOIN` does is include ALL records from the first table and ALL records from the joining table regardless if there are nulls in either table.

That is why you have to use a `coalesce` statement in the select clause to make sure you don't wind up with a null value in the result set.

Hope this works.

Comment: I think it's getting closer but it's still not there. The problem appears to be with this table (employer contribution) where it stores a bunch of different employer matches and amounts. There is a field in that table called MEMO_CD. I only want results where the MEMO_CD = H and also in the employee deduction table where the DED_CD = H. The DED_CD is the employee contribution to HSA and MEMO_CD is the employer contribution.

Comment: So basically the tables need to be joined on employee id, check date and then where both MEMO_CD and DED_CD = H code. Here's a screenshot of just one employee when I look at the full join versus both tables. Hopefully, it helps explain it better. I get 48.25 for the employer contribution amount. But that's for MEMO_CD = T and I don't want that. On the full join query, I'd want that to be 0.00

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the dataset:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=05650922404523166633

Comment: and if I try and add d.DED_CD = c.MEMO_CD to the join statement, it still doesn't work. I barely get any results

Comment: Well, look at the above modified query. I added a where clause that checks for each row that either the deducation table or contribution table has these fields with a value of 'H'.

Comment: Dangit. Still no dice. Take a look at the screenshot. It's still the same issue. That employee returns a value of 48.25 for the employer contribution but it should be 0.00. If you look at the queries, the 48.25 represents memo_cd = T in the table. I don't want that. Since that employee had no memo_cd = H in that table, it should have returned 0.00

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08485274778790693448

Comment: So I need a bit more data. Do you mean that BOTH tables have to have the value 'H' in this field. Please say on what exact conditions do you want a record to return.

Comment: Yes - my apologies. The criteria that should be returned is when DED_CD = H, it should return that value and when MEMO_CD = H, it should return that as well.

The easiest way to explain this is that the employee deductions for HSA are in one table (ded_cd = H). And the employer contribution is in another table (memo_cd = H). What I'm trying to do is combine results where in a single row, I have the employee ID, check date, employee contribution and employer contribution. In order to be uploaded to the vendor's site, it has to be in that format.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.EMPLID as EmployeeID, a.AL_AMOUNT as EmployeeContribution, ISNULL(b.AL_AMOUNT, 0) AS EmployerContribution, a.CHECK_DT
FROM PS_AL_CHK_DED as a
LEFT JOIN PS_AL_CHK_MEMO as b ON a.EMPLID = b.EMPLID AND a.CHECK_DT = b.CHECK_DT
WHERE a.AL_DEDCD = 'H'
ORDER BY a.CHECK_DT
```